# How to get the Id of listview items? I am using Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this database:

[image: I am using this database]

This is my `ListView`:

[image: This is my listview]

How will I get the ID of these items from Firebase.Suppose I click on Electrician button then the listview will show up the nearest electrician available but I want to show full details of the worker by fetching the ID's of the listview items in the next activity.How to do that. I have tried the following:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(available_worker.this,WorkerProfile.class);
            String workerid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
```

But I think it is not getting the reference so I am not getting the ID.
How to solve it?

Comment: So which worker id do you want to get, `id00000003`? Or he `uid` of the logged in user?

Comment: I want to get id000000003

Comment: this is my code link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1folc_0ObdzjKXC0RAutLsd3Z7PqqTaHv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I know Firebase.getUid() wont work as it will give me the user id but I want the worker id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution for that. As you have a `list` in which you add data as in the following line of code:

```
  list.add(elec.getFname().toString() + " " + elec.getLname().toString() + "\n" + elec.getAddress().toString());
//  ^
```

You should also have a list for the keys. So when you are iterating through the `DataSnapshot` to add that data to the list, beside that line of code you should also add the keys to the another list like so:

```
listOfKey.add(ds.getKey());
```

And to get the corresponding `key` inside your `onItemClick` like this:

```
String key = listOfKey.get(position);
```

Comment: how to get the listOfKey?

Comment: You should create another list, named `listOfKey` in the same way you did for the first list, right? Does it work?